# How do I abandon validations after single (important) failure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a class with some validations:

```
class HeyThere < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :check_something
  validate :check_something_property_1
  validate :check_something_property_2
  validate :check_something_property_3

  def check_something
    errors.add(:something, "not there") if something.nil?
  end

  def check_something_property_1
    errors.add(:something, "bad property 1") if something.property_1 > 10
  end

  def check_something_property_2
    errors.add(:something, "bad property 2") if something.property_2 == "ha!"
  end

  def check_something_property_3
    errors.add(:something, "bad property 3") if something.property_3
  end
end
```

The problem is, if something doesn't exist, the first validation triggers, but the second one throws an exception:

```
undefined method `property_1' for nil:NilClass
```

For the example, I gave general examples for the validations, but in reality, they are fairly complex.  I could change each one to `if something && something.property_N whatever`, but that feels hacky, and makes the code less-readable, plus, its not very DRY when the number of validations becomes larger.

Is there a way to cancel the remaining validations if the first one fails?

Answer (score 2):

Since they depend on each other, these shouldn't be separate validations. Do this:

```
class PastaRecipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :have_ingredients

  private

  def have_ingredients
    # Don't run the remaining validations if any one validation fails.
    have_pasta &&
      have_sauce &&
      have_water
  end

  def have_pasta
    errors.add(:pasta, "need to buy pasta!") unless pasta.purchased?
  end

  def have_sauce
    errors.add(:sauce, "need delicious sauce!") unless sauce.delicious?
  end

  def have_water
    errors.add(:water, "need to boil water!") unless water.boiled?
  end
end
```

Comment: Won't each of those methods (have_pasta, have_sauce, have_water) return nil?  e.g. Won't this always halt at have_pasta in the have_ingredients method?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to use if-else statements, I suggest using `raise` to halt the entire validation chain:

```
class HeyThere < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :check_something
  validate :check_something_property_1
  validate :check_something_property_2
  validate :check_something_property_3

  def check_something
    if something.nil?
      errors.add(:something, "not there") 
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, self 
    end
  end

  def check_something_property_1
    errors.add(:something, "bad property 1") if something.property_1 > 10
  end

  def check_something_property_2
    errors.add(:something, "bad property 2") if something.property_2 == "ha!"
  end

  def check_something_property_3
    errors.add(:something, "bad property 3") if something.property_3
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this.  I'm just using the validations module here, but it applies to active record models the same way.  There are a lot of different modifications that can be done to this, but this is almost the exact implementation I used.

- Must list validations in order
- Can be modified to halt on any error including instance.errors[:base]
- Can halt on ANY error using instance.errors.any?
- with_options method will actually pass the "unless: Proc" to each validation, so it actually
- runs for each validation
- with_options can be replaced by just putting if or unless conditions on each validation

---

Class definition.  Non-AR version. Same can be done with ActiveRecord::Base classes

```
class Skippy

  # wouldnt need to do this initialize on the ActiveRecord::Base model version 
  include  ActiveModel::Validations

  validate :first
  validate :second
  validate :halt_on_third
  validates_presence_of :or_halt_on_fourth
  with_options unless: Proc.new{ |instance| [:halt_on_thirds_error_key, :or_halt_on_fourth].any?{ |key| instance.errors[key].any? } } do |instance|
    instance.validate :wont_run_fifth
    instance.validates_presence_of :and_wont_run_sixth
  end

    # wouldn't need to do these on the ActiveRecord::Base model version 
    attr_accessor :attributes
    def initialize
      @attributes = { or_halt_on_fourth: "I'm here" }
    end
    def read_attribute_for_validation(key)
      @attributes[key]
    end

  def first
    errors.add :base, 'Base error from first'
  end

  def second
    errors.add :second, 'Just an error'
  end

  def halt_on_third
    errors.add :halt_on_thirds_error_key, 'Halting error' unless @donthalt
  end

  def wont_run_fifth
    errors.add :wont_run_fifth, 'ran because there were no halting errors'
  end
end
```

---

Demo

```
2.0.0 :040 > skippy = Skippy.new
 => #<Skippy:0x0000000d98c1c0 @attributes={:or_halt_on_fourth=>"I'm here"}>
2.0.0 :041 > skippy.errors.any?
 => false
2.0.0 :042 > skippy.valid?
 => false
2.0.0 :043 > skippy.errors.full_messages
 => ["Base error from first", "Second Just an error", "Halt on thirds error key Halting error"]
2.0.0 :044 > skippy.errors.clear
 => {}
2.0.0 :045 > skippy.instance_variable_set(:@donthalt, true)
 => true
2.0.0 :046 > skippy.errors.any?
 => false
2.0.0 :047 > skippy.valid?
 => false
2.0.0 :048 > skippy.errors.full_messages
 => ["Base error from first", "Second Just an error", "Wont run fifth ran because there were no halting errors", "And wont run sixth can't be blank"]
2.0.0 :049 > skippy.errors.clear; skippy.attributes = {}; skippy.errors.any?
 => false
2.0.0 :050 > skippy.valid?; skippy.errors.full_messages
 => ["Base error from first", "Second Just an error", "Or halt on fourth can't be blank"]
2.0.0 :051 >
```